# Modifying Poetry's virtual environment PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm using Poetry to manage dependencies - NOT as a packaging tool.
Given the following layout

```
.
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module.py
└── scripts
    └── my_script.py
```

Inside `my_script.py` I'm using `from src.my_module import MyClass` but when I call `poetry run python scripts/my_script.py` I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

I want to add the root directory to the `PYTHONPATH` of this specific environment, but I want to avoid manually exporting it everytime.

Bottom line I'm looking for Poetry's equivalent for [vitualenvwrappers add2virtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv)

Is this possible under Poetry?

Answer (score 3):

You can put your `my_module.py` directly into the `src` folder, but this is not recommended. Create a package folder first which then contains all your modules.

```
project
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── scripts
│   └── my_script.py
└── src
    └── project
        ├── __init__.py
        └── my_module.py
```

With a `pyproject.toml` like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["finswimmer <finswimmer@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Don't forget to run `poetry install` once. This will install the project in editable mode.

Comment: as I said, I DON'T want to use it as a packaging tool but rather for managing my environment dependencies... I never intend to use `poetry install`

Comment: You need to run `poetry install` to install your dependencies. Installing the project in editable mode is the last step of this procedure. What happens there is to store the meta data in the `site-packages` folder and also creating a `.pth` file which contains the parent folder to the package. Python will then add this path to `sys.path`. (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/site.html) Isn't this exactly what you want? If not it would be useful to describe what you really want to achieve and why.

Comment: Sorry my bad, obviously I used `install` - but I don't want to use the `src/project` structure, I want to have multiple things inside my `src` some are just `.py` files and some are packages and Iw ant to be able to import freely from them

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, I wrote a small `.sh` script, that permanently adds the project directory to the environment created by poetry.

This is the script, `add2pythonpath.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Add current folder to PYTHONPATH
CURRENT_FOLDER=$(pwd)
SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER="$(ls -d $(poetry env info -p)/lib/python*/site-packages/)project_dir.pth"
echo "$CURRENT_FOLDER" > "$SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER"
```

If you execute this inside your project directory, the current folder (project directory) will be permanently be added to the PYTHONPATH for your poetry created virtual environment.

It is utilizing `.pth` files to do so, you can read more about how those files are relevant for that in this link:
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#:~:text=A%20path%20configuration,tab](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#:%7E:text=A%20path%20configuration,tab))%20are%20executed.

Comment: adding `packages = [ { include = "**/*.py", from = "."  }]` in the `[tool.poetry]` of `config.toml` did it for me.